# is it possible to spoof the model of a router so it appears as something else in mobile network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

**Hello**, i have a Huawei router which connects by 4G to the phone company that i use, it supports many bands 1800\2300\2600.

The problem i have is that the phone company recently **restricted** the router and many popular routers from using the **1800 band** , and made it so only phones can use it (also unpopular routers could connect to the 1800 band until the company blocks them and restrict them to the 2300 band).

Anyway I don't think they have a huge database of all the IMEIs of routers in the country or something, they probably have blacklisted them by using the routers model\modem model (if you take the sim and put it in a phone it connect to the 1800 band).

I have tried connecting by telnet, but it doesn't seem to have that enabled, the only way i have of changing its settings is the web interface\firmware upload, is it possible to modify the huawei firmware\configuration of the router's update and change the model number to one of a phone?

Or does it require professional work (encrypted files\no tools to unpack\pack the firmware\etc..) the model is e5172s (i think it uses linux)

i know it was done before (dd-wrt\openwrt) i'm just asking how could it be done and since i don't want to add features or anything (just changing a string in a text file) i'd imagine it a lot easier.

Comment: Its MUCH more likely they just use different APNs for phone plans and home BB plans.

Comment: @Linef4ult i'm sure it's not the APN, it's just the device type, so i think it's probably related to the model number \ or other identfier

Comment: i tried unpacking the (.bin) firmware and i couldn't do it, i tried universal extractor\7-zip with no success, i'm downloading a tool that works on linux and try on ubuntu :D

Comment: How do you know they're blocking use of a band by certain CPE? That seems unusual as often not all bands will cover all areas so they'd create blackspots.

Comment: @Linef4ult because when you use other devices(phones\some obscure routers) they could connect to the band when it's available, but when you use most routers they only connect to the other band, they don't connect to the 1800 band even if the 2300 band isn't available(**and even if you forced it to connect to 1800 in settings**) so they just blacklisted routers, btw here the 1800 band is about 1000% faster than the 2300 that's absolutely a stupid move from the company, i have a great cable connection so this is a secondary internet but it just makes me want to connect because they blocked it :|